compare A and B's populations VS compare A's and B's populations
Note: A and B are the names of two countries.
Are both phrases in the title correct or is it only the latter?
To my mind, compare A and B's populations can mean that A and B share the same populations, which is misleading since I'm comparing their own population with each other's. However, I doubt if anybody would interpret it that way, so I'm not sure whether the former is acceptable or not. What do you think?

It would be more idiomatic to say compare the populations of A and B.

Thanks for your suggestion! How about compare A's and B's population? Is it still correct to use population in the singular? I once mistakenly wrote it that way in Word Office, but to my surprise, Grammarly didn't try to correct me, so I wonder if it's also acceptable.

Now that really does sound ambiguous, as though A and B share the same population (think of countries with dual names, like Trinidad and Tobago).


compare A and B's populations


compare A's and B's populations

As we are comparing A's population and B's, we use the second one.  The first one (with population rather than populations) is for joint possession like compare A and B's population with C's.
Edit
To avoid misunderstanding,  we could say
compare the total population of A and B with C's.

Is the double possessive "population of A's"   intentional?  I'd write "Population of A"

Thanks,  @James K.  I've edited. It's neater now.  The double possessive is unnecessary.

Thank you both for your answer and comment.
